# Widget boletim informativo "newsletter-ad" com problemas de formatação

Tags: bug, tradução, localização, layout

O widget na coluna lateral direita do site com a identificação `newsletter-ad` está com sérios problemas principalmente oriundos das traduções realizadas aos textos originais em Inglês:

[image: Captura de Tela]

## Problemas

1. O título não está traduzido;
2. O botão para registo contém demasiado texto causando um `overflow` horizontal;
3. As traduções estão a criar demasiado conteúdo o que causa um `overflow` vertical.

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicado? [Falha de Tradução/Layout](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/968/3117)

Comment: @Math É duplicado sim, estive a ver se já estava reportado, mas com um título tão genérico como está na outra pergunta não é fácil chegar lá :) _(vou votar para fechar como duplicado)_